# Exchange 2007: E-Mails not showing up, but have been delivered by E-Mail Security (SonicWall)

Tags: email, exchange, exchange-2007, email-server, sonicwall

I've a very strange problem:
SOME mails (I can't see a pattern) are not shown in our Outlook Exchange Accounts, but when I check the E-Mail Security Logs (we use a SonicWall), they seem to be delivered.

Does anyone have an idea where to begin with looking? I've controlled the settings, run all available updates for Exchange 2007 and checked the logs, but no results.

Thanks for any hint,
Joseph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Exchange Management Console toolbox "Message Tracking" feature to check if the messages in question actually were delivered by Exchange into the store.

If they were, there is not much logged beyond this point - there is no log for storage operations in Exchange's default configuration. You might consider changing this via the Set-EventLogLevel Powershell Cmdlet and evaluate your event logs or use some 3rd party tool like ExInsight to get an idea about what your users are doing to the store so that messages "disappear".

Comment: Thanks syneticon-dj. I've checked the Management Console and can see that the message(s) have been delivered to Exchange, but somehow they are not getting forwarded to the Clients (Outlook/OWA). I'll check out ExInsight and try to evaluate what Exchange is doing..

Comment: Emails don't get forwarded to the clients. The mailboxes exist ON the Exchange Server. Is it the case that the message tracking logs show that the messages have been delivered to the mailboxes?

Comment: The logs show an entry "Received" and an entry "Delivered" for an E-Mail, which is not shown on Outlook. I can provide you with some screenshots if you wish..

Comment: If the message tracking log shows a `DELIVER` event for the message, it WAS placed in the mailbox. Check rules in Outlook to see if the user has it going to a folder, automatically deleting it, or doing something else weird with it. Do you have antivirus or any other software on the Exchange server which could be eating them?